# Is there a way to access each user account in Volt?

Tags: voltrb

Is there a way to access each user account in Volt? I need to be able to click on a User._name and get to their account to see their details... How do I access the account of each user.?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, users are just part of the store.users collection, so you can access them and query them like you normally would for another collection.

store.users.all.each do |user|
  puts user.name
end